# Return non-nullable type with C# generics, accepting a nullable type

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I want a generic method which checks for null, if it's null it should throw an exception, if not, it should return the non-nullable type of it.

I have a generic method, called `GetRequiredValue`:

```
public static TValue GetRequiredValue<TClass, TValue>(this TClass obj, Expression<Func<TClass, TValue>> expression)
{ 
    // Omitted reflection logic to get property value of the object
    var value = ...;

    if (value is null) throw new Exception("Value is null.");
    
    return value;
}
```

A class, containing a nullable string property:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string? Name { get; set; }
}
```

When calling `GetRequiredValue`, the return type is of type `string?`, but I know it's the non-nullable version:

```
var val = obj.GetRequiredValue(x => x.Name); // return type is string?
```

Is it even possible to return the non-nullable type?

Comment: What dotnet/C# versions are we talking about? Is this in a #nullable enabled context?

Comment: @Fildor .NET 6, C# 10. And yes nullability is enabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is where [`NotNullAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.notnullattribute?view=net-7.0) should be used.

> Specifies that an output is not null even if the corresponding type allows it. Specifies that an input argument was not null when the call returns.

Annotate the return type of `GetRequiredValue` with it:

```
[return: NotNull]
public static TValue GetRequiredValue<TClass, TValue>(this TClass obj, Expression<Func<TClass, TValue>> expression)
```

See also: [Nullable static analysis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis#postconditions-maybenull-and-notnull)